# iPhone SDK Issue On Device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there any way to add a SDK to Xcode, so I can test my application on older devices, which are running that SDK.

I'd prefer the ability to test on iOS 3.0 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the base SDK in the project settings panel. You'll want to change it in the two panes, "Info" and "Build Settings"

Comment: Will that ensure my project runs on iOS 3.0?

Comment: It does run, I thought you had to test it in a simulator with iOS 3.0 to ensure it was compatible with that SDK

Comment: As long as you're not using some APIs that are iOS 4 specific, you should be fine. - One example I could think of would be the UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad, which was introduced in iOS 4.1. All the other keyboard types were introduced in 2.0.